# Why is hydrogen sulfate put together as it is?

Tags: bond, lewis-structure

I recently looked up hydrogen sulfate ($\ce{HSO4-}$) to see how it's put together, and found this image of methyl hydrogen sulfate:

[image: lewis structure of methylsulfate]

I'd assume that hydrogen sulfate looks the same, but without the methyl group attached. However I'm confused, how can it be constructed like that? This shows the sulfur having a total of 12 valence electrons, but shouldn't the maximum be 8?

I might be asking something that'll be obvious to me later on in chemistry, but this (and other groups that act as atoms) appear early on. I probably don't *need* to know it yet but I'd prefer to know how it works if I can as opposed to just accepting it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think it's time for you to know about Octet Expansion rule. The molecules that expand their octet are known as [Hypervalent Molecules](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervalent_molecule).

> Normally, atoms in group 2 have 8 electrons and can thus form 4 bonds.  This is mainly because they have s and p orbitals. However, in elements of group 3, they have extra orbitals called d orbitals that can be used to form more bonds.  when forming extra bonds, the atom promotes electrons into the d orbitals and allows the atom to from more than 4 bonds.

Same thing happens in the case of sulfur. Sulfur belongs to 3rd period and therefore it has a vacant 3d orbital and thus can accommodate more than 8 electrons in its valence cell.

Comment: I see. I know about orbitals so I suppose that makes sense. I hadn't heard of hypervalent molecules before though, so thanks!

Comment: The involvement of d orbitals in sulfur compounds is marginal (below 1%). Hypervalency and hybridisation are the most famous misunderstood concepts in chemistry.

Comment: @Martin : So what are you proposing here? o.O

Comment: As $\ce{SO4^{2-}}$ is isoelectronic with [$\ce{PO4^{3-}}$](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/13666/4945) I would simply suggest an analogous bonding picture. I.e. Only sigma single bonds to the oxygens, each carrying a negative charge and sulfur being positively charged. The bonding picture of $\ce{HSO4-}$ can then be derived accordingly.

Comment: @Martin : Well thanks for information. but I am still thinking that my answer is appropriate for OP or not. Since I wrote what I was taught about Hypervalency in 12th grade. I am not sure that OP is capable of taking any higher concepts. Should I take down my answer? :)

Comment: No definitely not. The concept you provide is/was, however outdated it is now, in use. Unfortunately it will almost certainly still be taught at some schools and it is hard to get rid of these myths - but then again some teach creation theory.

Comment: I'm starting out with my final year of high school chemistry (to be honest I'm redoing this from last year as I previously failed it), and I'm not sure whether hypervalency will be taught here or not. I think I understand Martin's explanation as well though. In any case my main goal was to find some explanation, and make sure I wasn't overlooking a simple one I should know. Whether I actually understand it now or later on isn't a huge concern.

Answer (score 7):

Hypervalency is an obsolete concept - it was used to explain bonding situations of molecules, that seem to exceed the octet rule. It was accomplished by the help of $\ce{spd}$ hybrid orbitals. It is now known, that for almost all molecules that were described this way the contribution of $\ce{d}$ orbitals is negligible (<1%).

Focussing on the question at hand, the bonding situation of the core $\ce{SO4^{2-}}$ anion is isoelectronic to the [phosphate anion $\ce{PO4^{3-}}$](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/13657/bonding-in-the-phosphate-ion/13666#13666).

For the methylsulfate this situation may be extended. A qualitative analysis of the natural charges (BP86/cc-pVDZ) reveals no difference. All of the oxygen atoms carry a negative charge, while sulfur is highly positive charged. Further more, NBO analysis confirms that the terminal oxygens have three lone pairs, while the other oxygens have two lone pairs. A more accurate Lewis structure would represent that fact and only use single bonds.

[image: charges][image: lewis structure]

Comment: While I can understand the hypervalency concept, if that's obsolete then this might be a bit too advanced for me. My current study material hints towards using the d orbital but still doesn't explain it, simply states that "some" atoms can hold up to 18 electrons, including sulphur and phosphorus, and that others like boron and beryllium are content with less than 8. My main issue is because they are exceptions to the octet rule when drawing Lewis structure, but at this point I don't think there's much I can do besides memorising them. All the same, thanks a lot!