# What is the bonding picture in Peroxomonosulfate?

Tags: bond, ions, lewis-structure

In $\ce{SO5^{2-}}$, can somebody tell me which orbitals are used to form the pi bonds in this anion.
Please tell the hybridization.
And the lewis structure.

Well I tried and the answers I got was sp3 & the pi bonds are formed using d orbitals.I just need to know whether I'm correct

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! To acquaint yourself with this page, take the [tour](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help). Furthermore [this tutorial](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/88/189) shows you how math and chemical formulae can be nicely formatted on this site. Finally, we have an important policy: your questions (especially [homework questions](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/142/189)), should show your own work or thinking that you have already done in an initial attempt to answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is already the Lewis structure

[image: Here is already the Lewis structure]

Comment: This question violates our [Homework policy](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange). While your effort to answer this problem is very much appreciated, it would be better if you vote (or flag) this question to be closed. We are not a homework answering service.

Comment: I see, sorry I'm rather new on the website, I just wnted give a little help :x

Answer (score 3):

The peroxomonosulfate is a [hypercoordinated molecule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervalent_molecule#Criticism), in which the sulfur appears to exceed Lewis' rule of two, better known as the [octet rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octet_rule). In former times it was believed that d orbitals would contribute to bonding. This is *not* the case.
Bonding is better represented by

- three equivalent $\ce{S-O}$ single bonds
- sulfur having a formal charge of +2
- these three oxygens having a formal charge of -1
- one $\ce{S-O}$ single bond that leads to the peroxyl oxygen
- this oxygen has a formal charge of zero
- one $\ce{O-O}$ single bond
- and the terminal oxygen having a formal charge of -1

This bonding picture is much more in accordance with quantum chemical calculations and an NBO analysis on the DF-BP86/def2-SVP level of theory. The involvement of d orbitals is minimal (<1%).
[image]

It is noteworthy, that this molecule pretty much has the same bonding around the sulphur as in sulphate. It can therefore similarly be described. Have a look at my rant [against hypervalency](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/13896/4945) or the [bonding picture of the $\ce{PO4^{3-}}$ anion](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/13657/4945), which is isoelectronic to sulphate.